# HelpBar in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to develop Help Bar in HTML for which i am using following code.Is
there any way so that i can make it small in terms of number of lines.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td  width="400" height="50" >
<input type="button"  value="HOME" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'" >
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button"   value="ABOUT US" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button"  value="CONTACT US" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use a table, use appropriate tags and CSS
2. Get rid of all those `&nbsp;` characters and use CSS to add margins
3. Use `<a>` tags instead of buttons, and style them with CSS
4. Don't uppercase your words in the markup, use CSS (`text-transform:uppercase`)
5. For the sake of all that is good, use an `href` instead of a javascript `onclick` event.
6. Learn CSS!

Resulting HTML should look something like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

With CSS you will be able to get the same look you had with the table and buttons, but **much** more, and you will be using best practices, have greater accessibility, as well as easy maintenance, editing, control over your page's appearance, and simpler, sensible markup

Remember:

- HTML - Describes what the content **is**
- CSS - Describes what the content **looks like**

Some good reference reading for the future:

- http://www.htmldog.com/

Comment: It is a list of links. Use a list, not a div.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, I was adding that as you typed your comment. This is most likely a throwaway answer anyways, but I admit I'm getting sleepy and not thinking normally. I've never used a div with naked `<a>`'s in my life...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply combine it all onto one line if you want:

```
<table><tr><td width="400" height="50"><input type="button" value="HOME" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"   value="ABOUT US" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="CONTACT US" onClick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com'"></td>
```

Comment: Yeah, I red. Now you see the @Wesley Murch's answer.

Comment: The question was for "small in terms of number of lines".  Without more info it's not clear what @Eshika was after. E.g. maybe he needed to quickly fit his HTML into a single line because the webmaster he was giving it to made that requirement.  Who knows?  This is why people should ask clear questions -- and not downvote *correct* and direct answers like this one.  Downvote incorrect or misleading answers and upvote good ones.